# C# call synchronous methods from asynchronous methods

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to call a synchronous method from with an async one?

Doing the following results in a compiler error:

```
DoSomething synchronously blocks. Await DoSomethingAsync instead
```

```
public async Task<int> DoStuff(bool runAsync) {
    int result;
    if (runAsync) {
        result = await DoSomethingAsync();
    } else {
        result = DoSomething();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Potentially related? https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/issues/541

What are the options here, is it possible to add a comment for the compiler to ignore?

Thanks!

Comment: Your method signature makes no sense at all, rather, the proper way is to have `DoStuff` and `DoStuffAsync` methods.

Comment: This is most definitely an x/y problem, explain why you think you need this, and we will explain the options and why you dont

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the link given below which is related to this event and also here the they call the `synchronous` method `asynchronously`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/calling-synchronous-methods-asynchronously

Answer (score -1):

From looking deeper at the documentation, a comment can be added as :

```
#pragma warning disable VSTHRD103
...
#pragma warning restore VSTHRD103
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).